# JSON data question while working on SAPUI5

Tags: json, sapui5

I'm trying to familiarize with the JSON data structure. Can anyone detect what's wrong with the following converted json data structure

I have the following JSON data directly injected to the model, which works beautifully

```
this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
                dataset1: [
                    { value: 4 },
                    { value: 3 },
                    { value: 2 },
                    { value: 1.5 },
                    { value: 3 }
                ],
                dataset2: [
                    { value: 3 },
                    { value: 3 },
                    { value: 3 },
                    { value: 3 },
                    { value: 3 }
                ],
                options: {
                    scaleOverride: false,
                    scaleStartValue: 0,
                    scaleSteps: 5,
                    scaleStepWidth: 1
                }
            }));
```

however as i converted it to data.json and load the file, it fails. The declaration as following:

```
{
    "dataset1": [
        { "value": 4 },
        { "value": 3 },
        { "value": 2 },
        { "value": 1.5 },
        { "value": 3 }
    ],
    "dataset2": [
        { "value": 3 },
        { "value": 3 },
        { "value": 3 },
        { "value": 3 },
        { "value": 3 }
    ],
    "options": {
        "scaleOverride": false,
        "scaleStartValue": 0,
        "scaleSteps": 5,
        "scaleStepWidth": 1
    }
}
```

Following code loads the json file

```
            var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.loadData("model/data.json");

            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Comment: What's the error message in the browser console?

Comment: Sorry. the error hits on some other parts which i can't really understand... I was trying this radarchart example which it works once imported --> https://github.com/jpenninkhof/pentagon

Comment: Kindly share your console error